# how many $2\times2$ matrices exist with this condition?

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic

Let $p=10007$ which is prime. I want to find the number of matrices X of $2\times2$ dimension with elements from $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for which $X^2\equiv I$ (mod $p$). Where $I$ - identity matrix. How can I solve this problem? I tried to write down the square of matrix so that I get the system of congruences, but I can't figure out what to do after that, and I don't think this is the right way to solve this.

Comment: If $X^2=I$ then the minimum polynomial for $X$ is $y^2-1,y-1,$ or $y+1.$ This means $X$ is either $\pm I$ or $\operatorname{tr} X=0,\det X=-1.$ So $$X=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$$ with $a+d=0,ad-bc=-1.$

Comment: That’s a great observation, but I don’t think this will lead to solution.

Comment: The observation by Thomas Andrews in fact leads to exactly the same case analysis Alan Abraham does in his answer.

Answer (score 6):

Let's say $X=\begin{bmatrix} a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$, after computing $X^2$, we get the following system of congruences
$$\begin{cases} a^2+bc\equiv 1\mod p\\b(a+d)\equiv 0\mod p\\c(a+d)\equiv 0\mod p\\d^2+bc\equiv 1\mod p\end{cases}$$

The $2$nd and $3$rd equations are simple to solve, so we will do casework on the those. We either have $b,c\equiv 0\mod p$ or $a+d\equiv 0\mod p$. There is also some overlap between these two cases, so we have to watch out for overcounting

**Case 1:** $b,c\equiv 0\mod p$
Then we have
$$\begin{cases} a^2\equiv 1\mod p\\d^2\equiv 1\mod p\end{cases}$$
There are clearly $2$ solutions for each of the congruences ($a,d\equiv \pm 1\mod p$), for a total of $4$ solutions. Since the $2$ solutions when $a\equiv -d\mod p$ overlap with the second case, we will exclude those for a total of $\boxed{2}$.

**Case 2:** $a+d\equiv 0\mod p$
Then we have
$$bc\equiv 1-a^2\equiv 1-d^2\mod p$$
We will split this case into sub cases depending on the values of $a,d$.

**Case 2a:** $a^2,d^2\equiv 1\mod p$
The solutions for $a,d$ are $a\equiv \pm 1\mod p,d\equiv \mp 1\mod p$. Hence there are $2$ solutions for $a,d$.
To find the number of solutions for $b,c$, we need to find the number of solutions to
$$bc\equiv 0\mod p$$
This only happens if at least $1$ of $b,c$ is equivalent to $0\mod p$. We must be careful to not double count the solutions of $b,c\equiv 0\mod p$. We get a total of $p+p-1=2p-1$ solutions for $b,c$.

Hence, there are $2(2p-1)=\boxed{4p-2}$ solutions for this subcase.

**Case 2b:** $a^2,d^2\equiv k\not\equiv 1\mod p$
Since $a,d\not\equiv -1,1\mod p$, there are $p-2$ ordered pairs to choose for $(a,d)$. Each of these generate a $k$ that satisfies $1-k\not\equiv 0\mod p$.

To find the solutions for $b,c$, these satisfy
$$bc\equiv 1-k\mod p$$
Since $1-k\not\equiv 0\mod p$, we have that
$$gcd(b,p)=1\implies c\equiv (1-k)b^{-1}\mod p$$
Hence, there is a unique solution for all $b\in[1,p-1]$.

The total in this subcase is $(p-1)(p-2)=\boxed{p^2-3p+2}$

---

Totaling all of these up, the number of solutions for $X$ is
$$2+(4p-2)+(p^2-3p+2)$$
$$\boxed{\boxed{p^2+p+2}}$$

This formula should only work when $p>2$. This is because throughout the process we assumed $1\not\equiv -1\mod p$. Upon substituting $p=10007$, we get the total number of solutions is $\boxed{100150058}$.

Comment: Case 2a is not really different from 2c.

Comment: Oops, I was thinking that there would be some problem in counting when $a\equiv d$, so I separated them. However, that was just a lapse in my judgement.

Comment: What is the problem with @Ovi solution then?

Comment: @BeesaFangirlDOTO I'm not sure (as idk Abstract Algebra). There might be some problem with my solution, but I have expressed my doubts with Ovi's solution. I am still interested in a more elegant solution.

Comment: Also I can’t see why Case 2a and 2c are not differ much in your solution?

Comment: @BeesaFangirlDOTO Refer to the earlier comments on this answer. They do not differ much, but I was overcautious and had a lapse of judgement, which lead me to separating them.

Comment: @BeesaFangirlDOTO: Case 2a is just case 2c with $k=0$, and there's actually nothing in the analysis of 2c that depends on $k\ne 0$.

Comment: @AlanAbraham, good job! The potential for lightening the argument by some abstraction may be of interest to you, and useful both in EE and math, for sure. But/and your insights are exactly on the money. :)

Answer (score 5):

As in @ThomasAndrews' comment, there is indeed a systematic (not-so-computational) way to approach this, maybe less lending itself to computational errors and such.

So, for a two-by-two matrix with $x^2=1$, certainly $x^2-1=0$, so either $x-1=0$, or $x+1=0$, or neither holds, but $x^2-1=0$.

In the first two cases, $x$ is $\pm$ the identity matrix, that is, has either eigenvalue $1$ (with multiplicity $2$) or eigenvalue $-1$ (with multiplicity $2$).

In the third case, necessarily $x$ has eigenvalues $1$ and $-1$. By standard linear algebra (!!!), this means that there is an invertible two-by-two matrix $A$ such that
$$
x \;=\; Ax_oA^{-1}
$$
with
$$
x_o \;=\; \pmatrix{1 & 0 \cr 0 & -1}
$$
Two matrices $A$ and $B$ produce the same $x$ if and only if
$$
x_o \;=\; (B^{-1}A)x_o(B^{-1}A)^{-1}
$$
That is, $B^{-1}A$ is in the *normalizer* of $x_o$. We can check that this normalizer is a *subgroup* of the two-by-two invertible matrices. For $g=\pmatrix{a & b\cr c & d}$, the condition $gx_og^{-1}=x_o$ (multiplied out) is equivalent to $b=c=0$, *if* $-1\not=+1$, which does hold for $p\not=2$. That is, for $p\not=2$, the normalizer consists of diagonal matrices.

Thus, the collection of matrices $x$ with eigenvalues $1$ and $-1$ is in bijection with the coset space of two-by-two invertible matrices by the subgroup of diagonal invertible matrices.

The number of diagonal matrices is $(q-1)^2$, while the cardinality of two-by-two invertible matrices is $(q^2-1)(q^2-q)$. Thus, the number of such matrices $x$ is the quotient, namely, $(q+1)q$.

Thus, adding the identity and negative identity, we get $(q+1)q+1+1=q^2+q+2$. (Matching Alan Abrahams more concrete computation.)